# looking for solution timestamp postgresql

Tags: sql, vb.net, postgresql, date, timestamp

hello my friends I got tired of looking for a solution I have a postgresql database that has a timestamp column I want to extract the values ​​this way

`2010-01-01 14:34:43`

without the milliseconds how to do this I want it 
`2010-01-01 14:34:43` 
and he shows me like this
`2010-01-01 14:34:43.267543`

Comment: Why the vb.net tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to discard the milliseconds you can use `date_trunc()`:

```
date_trunc('second', mytimestamp)
```

On the other hand if you want to *round* to the closest second, you can cast to `timestamp(0)`:

```
mytimestamp::timestamp(0)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4d4f6f0c135b8df99b3e86f6b113bc68)** - I used a timestamp whose tens of seconds is greater than `5` to make the test representative:

```
select
    mytimestamp,
    date_trunc('second', mytimestamp) trunc_mytimestamp,
    mytimestamp::timestamp(0) round_mytimestamp
from (values('2010-01-01 14:34:43.567543'::timestamp)) as t(mytimestamp)
```

```
mytimestamp                | trunc_mytimestamp   | round_mytimestamp  
:------------------------- | :------------------ | :------------------
2010-01-01 14:34:43.567543 | 2010-01-01 14:34:43 | 2010-01-01 14:34:44
```